# jquery alert not appearing

Tags: jquery, html

Am trying to load my jquery script but when I load the page, the alert message does not appear. The file main.js is saved in the same folder where I have the index.html page so I used this to call the page but nothing is happening and I don't see anything wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Here my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In veniam doloremque voluptate debitis quaerat ipsum, officia, ad exercitationem placeat quasi nobis enim itaque. Adipisci ullam magnam sequi eum maiores, quia!</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
( function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function (){
        alert('This shit is not working');
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: You need to move <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script> after <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Azeez Kallayi you are just about right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In veniam doloremque voluptate debitis quaerat ipsum, officia, ad exercitationem placeat quasi nobis enim itaque. Adipisci ullam magnam sequi eum maiores, quia!</p>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

you need first to include jQuery, then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You must load the jquery library first then load your jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

try It Once